# Insert Select Multiple rows

Tags: mysql

Hi I am new to mysql I can successfully insert one row but I wanted to insert three row but i been spending hours thinking how if anyone can advice or help me I will really appreciate it thank you

```
INSERT INTO earning (id, dateCreated,
dateModified,
x_t_name,
x_start_date,
x_end_month,
x_address,x_category,x_pic,x_promo_space,x_start_month,x_space_query,x_organizer,x_end_date 
,x_address_query,x_current_pic,x_start_year
,x_end_year
,x_event_title
,x_pix_name),

SELECT x_add1,dateCreated,dateModified,"","2018-11-01",
x_end_month,"address1","",x_current_pic,"",x_start_month,"''","", "2018-11-12","'address1'"
,x_current_pic,x_end_year,x_end_year,"",""
  FROM Sale
 WHERE id = 'x1'
```

but then I wanted to insert in multiple rows I am assigning different id and address

I tried like this but I know its wrong

```
INSERT INTO earning (id, dateCreated,
dateModified,
x_t_name,
x_start_date,
x_end_month,
x_address,x_category,x_pic,x_promo_space,x_start_month,x_space_query,x_organizer,x_end_date 
,x_address_query,x_current_pic,x_start_year
,x_end_year
,x_event_title
,x_pix_name),

(id, dateCreated,
dateModified,
x_t_name,
x_start_date,
x_end_month,
x_address,x_category,x_pic,x_promo_space,x_start_month,x_space_query,x_organizer,x_end_date 
,x_address_query,x_current_pic,x_start_year
,x_end_year
,x_event_title
,x_pix_name),

(id, dateCreated,
dateModified,
x_t_name,
x_start_date,
x_end_month,
x_address,x_category,x_pic,x_promo_space,x_start_month,x_space_query,x_organizer,x_end_date 
,x_address_query,x_current_pic,x_start_year
,x_end_year
,x_event_title
,x_pix_name)

SELECT x_add1,dateCreated,dateModified,"","2018-11-01",
x_end_month,"address1","",x_current_pic,"",x_start_month,"''","", "2018-11-12","'address1'"
,x_current_pic,x_end_year,x_end_year,"",""
  FROM Sale
 WHERE id = 'x1'


    SELECT x_add2,dateCreated,dateModified,"","2018-11-01",
x_end_month,"address2","",x_current_pic,"",x_start_month,"''","", "2018-11-12","'address2'"
,x_current_pic,x_end_year,x_end_year,"",""
  FROM Sale
 WHERE id = 'x1'


    SELECT x_add13,dateCreated,dateModified,"","2018-11-01",
x_end_month,"address3","",x_current_pic,"",x_start_month,"''","", "2018-11-12","'address3'"
,x_current_pic,x_end_year,x_end_year,"",""
  FROM Sale
 WHERE id = 'x1'
```

Comment: If you want to add several rows is not possible in one sentence (Only with a store procedure or a programming language ) you need to create several insert sql sentences. `INSERT INTO earning (id, dateCreated,
dateModified,
` then another sentence `INSERT INTO earning (id, dateCreated,
dateModified,
`

Comment: @mariohidalgo why do you say that?

Comment: @Strawberry  because the syntax that Aika is using is incorrect.

Comment: @mariohidalgo so, now you're saying it is possible in one sentence ? I'm confused

Comment: @Strawberry I said that it is necessary to declare several `insert into` sentences.

Comment: @mariohidalgo But it isn't :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184360/discussion-between-mario-hidalgo-and-strawberry).

Comment: @mariohidalgo by way of a quick demonstration... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g5kGYG9LSZTRDK6m7z32ek/0

Comment: thank you very much for responding to my question all of you are very nice thank you I really appreciate your help, time and effort thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert all the values by using a `UNION` on your `SELECT` queries. Note that the default behaviour for `UNION` is to remove duplicate rows, so if you want to have them in the table you would need to change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.

```
INSERT INTO earning (id, dateCreated,
dateModified,
x_t_name,
x_start_date,
x_end_month,
x_address,x_category,x_pic,x_promo_space,x_start_month,x_space_query,x_organizer,x_end_date 
,x_address_query,x_current_pic,x_start_year
,x_end_year
,x_event_title
,x_pix_name)
SELECT x_add1,dateCreated,dateModified,"","2018-11-01",
x_end_month,"address1","",x_current_pic,"",x_start_month,"''","", "2018-11-12","'address1'"
,x_current_pic,x_end_year,x_end_year,"",""
  FROM Sale
 WHERE id = 'x1'
UNION
    SELECT x_add2,dateCreated,dateModified,"","2018-11-01",
x_end_month,"address2","",x_current_pic,"",x_start_month,"''","", "2018-11-12","'address2'"
,x_current_pic,x_end_year,x_end_year,"",""
  FROM Sale
 WHERE id = 'x1'
UNION
    SELECT x_add13,dateCreated,dateModified,"","2018-11-01",
x_end_month,"address3","",x_current_pic,"",x_start_month,"''","", "2018-11-12","'address3'"
,x_current_pic,x_end_year,x_end_year,"",""
  FROM Sale
 WHERE id = 'x1'
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked thank you so much really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

To insert multiple rows, use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES
    (Value1a, Value2a, Value3a, ...),
    (Value1b, Value2b, Value3b, ...),
    (Value1c, Value2c, Value3c, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax is

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

You can try by adding another statement in the where clause as following

```
WHERE id = 'x1' and x_address IN (address1, address2, address3)
```